# Where is the database call in the Repository Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I've looked over several repository pattern examples and I can't seem to determine where the database access takes place. All of the examples I'm seeing seem to anticipate the use of the Entity Framework, which is outside of the scope of the small project I'm doing. I'm trying to create a WebAPI service that will have 5 or so models/controllers.

Basically, my question is: how do I integrate my db calls into the project and where? Should I call a DAL method directly from the controller, which seems anti-pattern? The database context in the controller is how it's done using the EF in the examples, but I don't know **where** that is actually passed to the controller via property or constructor.

### EDIT:

*Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I apologize for that. I'm not using the Entity Framework. I have no interest in using the EF. I'm not going to be using it at any point in my project.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have to use ADO.NET directly, right?

Here is a sample repos:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>
{
    public UserRepository(AdoNetContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public void Create(User user)
    {
        using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Users (CompanyId, FirstName) VALUES(@companyId, @firstName)";
            command.AddParameter("companyId", user.CompanyId);
            command.AddParameter("firstName", user.FirstName);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        //todo: Get identity. Depends on the db engine.
    }


    public void Update(User user)
    {
        using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"UPDATE Users SET CompanyId = @companyId WHERE Id = @userId";
            command.AddParameter("companyId", user.CompanyId);
            command.AddParameter("userId", user.Id);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM Users WHERE Id = @userId";
            command.AddParameter("userId", id);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> FindUsers(string firstName)
    {
        using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CompanyId = @companyId AND FirstName LIKE @firstName";
            command.AddParameter("companyId", LoggedInUser.companyId);
            command.AddParameter("firstName", firstName + "%");
            return ToList(command);
        }
    }    

    public IEnumerable<User> FindBlocked()
    {
        using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Status = -1";
            return ToList(command);
        }
    }    

    protected void Fill(IDataRecord record, User user)
    {
        user.FirstName = (string)record["FirstName"];
        user.Age = (int)record["Age"];
    }
}
```

It's from my [ADO.NET, the right way](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/) article.

Comment: AddParameter should be ("@property"), right? Good suggestion, though. I'm trying to use the pattern properly, but I couldn't find a single example on where to implement data access without EF. With yours, the repository basically doubles as the DAL.

Comment: IIRC No, there is no need for the `@` in `AddParameter()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an Entity Framework data within you controller, then you can pass it into the constructor using an Inversion of Control container framework. The framework will automatically create an instance the data context and then an instance of your WebApi controller passing in the data context its just created.

This is an example of a framework that will allow this:

http://nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi/

https://code.google.com/p/autofac/w/list

EDIT 1:

If you don't want to use the Entity Framework, then take the same approach but instead of passing in the data context into your WebApi controller you can pass in an ADO.NET connection.

EDIT 2:

You should look into the Unit of Work and Repository patterns. The Unit Of Work is responsible for managing your database connection/data context/etc and will also create instances of your repositories. Each respository will then manage the entities within each table and how you read/update these entities.

My initial response then applies, but instead of the data context it would be an instance of your Unit of Work class.

There are a number of good examples of these patterns and the use of Autofac on stackoverflow and the internet, so I won't try to repeat them here. Note that I mention Autofac, but it is possible to use any IoC container that supports ASP.NET WebApi.

Comment: I've already said I didn't want to use EF. It's overkill for what I'm doing.

Comment: To access the database you will need to use some kind of database framework whether its Entity Framework, Linq to SQL or ADO.NET. How do you want to access the database?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I don't know where it goes in the actual pattern.

Comment: Read up on the Unit of Work and Repository patterns. The Unit of Work manages your data context (whatever data access library you decide to use) and the repository manages how you read/update entities within a table. You then pass the Unit of Work into the WebApi constructor using an IoC as mentioned in my answer. There are plenty of examples on how to do this on stackoverflow and the internet in general.